# Handlebars.js: Find object by Index

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm new to handlebars.js
here's my data structure (pseudo-Code)

```
{
  News = list of news;
  Ads = list of add;
}
```

What I try to do is access the Ads by the News' index (I made sure the indexes exists, no problem there). An add consists of multiple properties

- Link
- Source
- Title

When I call

```
{{../Ads.[0]}
```

It works, I can access the ad but as soon as I use @key

```
{{../Ads.[@key]}
```

handlebars.js doesn't find anything. I assume that is because @key is a string and not an integer.
But I found no way to convert it to an integer. Tried a helper which converts @key to an integer but I have no idea how to use it because

```
//template markup
{{../Ads.[numericIndex @key]}}
```

doesn't yield a result too.

So, what I came up with is the following (which works)

```
{{#ad../Ads index = @@key}}{{this}}{{/ad}}

//the helper, just a basic example
Handlebars.registerHelper('ad', function (ads, options) {

     return "<strong>" + options.fn(ads[parseInt(options.hash.index)].Source) + "</strong>";
});
```

But I wonder what would be the best way to achieve what I want.
Sure, my solution works but it feels kinda clumsy.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

As requested by Jivings here is what I want to achieve. This what I want to output as an ad (I used handlebars' template tags to show want I want to display. All the properties here belong to "ad")
This should be outputted for every news I loop through.

Hope this helps

```
<div class="ad col-sm-12" title="{{Title}}">
   <a href="{{Link}}">{{Source}}</a>
</div>
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: Could you instead post the HTML you are trying to output? It's possible there's an easier solution for what you want.

Comment: @Arikael Is "Ads" in your object equal to an array? Can you take the length of "Ads" with Ads.length?

Comment: yes it is and length returns the correct number